# Looping over a "Marker" inside a Step Function and aggregate results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to get all clusters in a EMR instance using [EMR:ListCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_ListClusters.html)
But, as it's said:

> This call returns a maximum of 50 clusters in unsorted order per call,
> but returns a marker to track the paging of the cluster list across
> multiple ListClusters calls.

And we may have more than 50 instances.

So I have this Step function:

```json
{
  "StartAt": "Pass (1)",
  "States": {
    "Pass (1)": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "ListActiveClusters",
      "Result": {
        "Clusters": [],
        "Marker": null
      }
    },
    "ListActiveClusters": {
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterStates": [
          "STARTING",
          "BOOTSTRAPPING",
          "RUNNING",
          "WAITING",
          "TERMINATED"
        ],
        "Marker.$": "$.Marker"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:emr:listClusters",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Choice"
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.Marker",
              "IsPresent": true
            },
            {
              "Not": {
                "Variable": "$.Marker",
                "IsNull": true
              }
            }
          ],
          "Next": "ListActiveClusters"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Pass"
    },
    "Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

which effectively loop over "ListActiveClusters":
[image: Step function call]

the results look like:

[image: Results of listClusters]
but I can't find a way to cumulate the results ("$.Clusters") of the calls into a single array.
Would you have a solution ? (as a last resort, I could make the call from a lambda)

Thanks :)